# How to get the number of rows count of a Excel file in Java script which was uploaded via html input file tag

Tags: javascript, html, excel, dojo

I have  a requirement in which I need to get the number of rows in a Excel file which was uploaded via html file tag. It is a web application where we get the file in a JSP. Please help me on this

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code written?  Check out the Asking section in our [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: You need to include a filereader for reading the excel to determine number of rows

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and did this in service layer using Java.
If you want to do in javascript, try these two libraries
– js-xls
– js-xlsx